# Stop caching for a specific node (by nid) Drupal 7

Tags: theming, caching

Ideally i want to set custom params for caching in some particular nodes using conditions in my **template.php**

***E.g. algorithm:*** for node with known **nid** set custom caching params

But that's enough for my purpose simply exclude from caching particular node.
I fond this solution: [Stop caching for a specific node type Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26938/) this is exacly what im looking for but how i can change condition of checking from node type to nid.

I know about [CacheExclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude) module, but for me unwanted to install module for just exclude one node for caching.

I'll be very grateful for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A module with the below in it should stop caching on node 2. Change the number to do it on a different node id.

```
function MYMODULE_init(){
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 2) {
    drupal_page_is_cacheable(FALSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: `arg()` is evil.  Using `menu_get_object()` to get/check the current node is a much better solution.

Comment: why is `arg()` evil? I thought it would be better not to load a whole node just to check nid